# Overlap with negative margin and float

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that looks like this:

[image: Navigation bar]

and recently decided to replace PNG arrows in it with CSS. The only problem, with CSS arrows overlap doesn't work as expected. The next nav block overlaps the preceding arrow, hiding it, while it's the arrow that should overlap the next nav block (which is the case when using images). If I remove the negative margin from .navarrow, a gap between navblocks appears like on the image above.

Is there a way I can achieve desired effect (preceding .navarrow overlaps the .navblock that follows)? CSS arrows are much preferred, since their colors can be changed easily.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navblock home"><a href="/">Home</a></div>
    <div class="navarrow"></div>
    <div class="navblock category"><a href="/apparel/">Apparel</a></div>
    <div class="navarrow"></div>
    <div class="navblock group"><a href="/apparel/jeans/"></a>Jeans</div>
    <div class="navarrow"></div>
    <div class="navblock item">Bla-bla</div>
    <div class="navarrow"></div>
</div>

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.navblock {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 0 40px;
}

/* triangle pointing to the right */
.navarrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid green;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -20px; /* overlap */
}
```

Comment: So you WANT an overlap? It would be helpful to see a screenshot or something of the desired appearance. (http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/PjhBg/)

Comment: I'm not sure what look it is that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Possibly a better approach would be to use a `ul` for the navigation and `:after` in the css to create the arrows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope my example help you

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/eju9r/14/

Comment: Using canvas for simple triangles is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

somthing like this ...i try it eith canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/eju9r/4/

Comment: Wow! That's an interesting way of doing it, but overlap still doesn't work as expected. Just add the negative margin back to .navblock or .navarrow to check this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to change your markup a little to do this.

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Apparel</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; }
.navbar li { float: left; }
.navbar li a { 
    background: url(left_image.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: block; }
.navbar li a span {
    background: url(arrow.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/UdbnG/

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've figured it out guys.

Just added **position: relative** and **left: 0** to *.navarrow* so that it now looks like this:

```
.navarrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

[image]